# Issues With checking int in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq-to-sql, c#-3.0

I am trying to check the int values in an array and based on that do some calculation but the code is not working below is the code:

```
string EventIds = getVoucher.EventIDs;

int[] array = EventIds.Split(',')
                      .Select(x => int.Parse(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                      .ToArray();

if(array.ToString().Any(s => booking.EventID.ToString().Contains(s)))
{do something; } else { do something;}
```

Comment: if I dont convert array into string then I cant use LInq expression 'Any' nd 'Contains'

Comment: You'll have to tell us what you want it to do that it isn't, and what it is doing that you wish it wouldn't... :)

Comment: the array[] contains the value for instance 23 , 24,25 .. I want to check that with the EventId value passed which is an integer (1,2,3..), If an array contains the Event ID then it should do some calculation else throw an error , hope it make sense

Comment: That makes a lot more sense.  I think @dtb's answer is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array.ToString` returns the string `"System.Int32[]"`. Using `Any` with a string checks the predicate for each *character*  in the string.

Assuming that `booking.EventID` is an `int` such as `1234`, `booking.EventID.ToString()` returns the string `"1234"`.

So your code checks if `"1234"` contains any character in `"System.Int32[]"` (here: `true`, because `"1234"` contains the `'3'` of `"System.Int32[]"`).

---

You don't say what the desired result is, but I guess you're looking for something like this:

```
if (array.Any(s => booking.EventID == s))
{
    // ...
}
```

or

```
if (Array.IndexOf(array, booking.EventID) != -1)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you try to convert to string array?

```
array.ToString();//???
```

this code will return 
System.Int32[]

remove the ToString()!!!
if you want to enumerate the array use this code instead

```
array.AsEnumerable().Any(...
```

Comment: I have added comment which will make it more clear to understand what i m looking for

Answer (score 1):

```
// cache it to avoid multiple time casting
string bookingId = booking.EventID.ToString();

// you can do filtering in the source array without converting it itno the numbers
// as long as you won't have an Exception in case when one of the Ids is not a number
if(EventIds.Split(',').Any(s => bookingId.Contains(s)))
{
  // ..
}
else
{
 // ...
}
```

Also, depends on how source array is generated you should consider Strign.Trim() to remove spaces:

```
if(EventIds.Split(',').Any(s => bookingId.Contains(s.Trim())))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
if (
        EventIds.Split(',').OfType<string>()
            .Any(e => booking.EventID.ToString().Contains(e))
    )
{
    //Some member of a comma delimited list is part of a booking eventID ???
}
else
{
    //Or Not
}
```

If this is not what you wanted to do then your code is wrong.

EDIT:

After reading you comment I think you want the more logical

```
If (EventIDs.Split(',').Select(s => 
    int.Parse(s)).OfType<int>().Contains(booking.EventID))
{
    //Ther booking ID is in the list
}
else
{
    //It isn't
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a "ToArray()", try doing a "ToList()".   you can than use the "Contains" method to search.